# Need help with paypal integration for mutiple item

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am getting error "some information missing.." on paypal when my site will redirect to paypal.
following is html page and code behind from where control goes to payapl

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>PayPal Payment Detail</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function submitform() {

        var frm = this.document.getElementById('confirmOrder1');
        frm.submit();
    }
</script>
 </head>
<body onload="submitform();">
<form name="confirmOrder1" runat="server" id="confirmOrder1" method="post">
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="cmd" name="cmd" />    
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="business" name="business" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" runat="server" id="no_shipping" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" id="return" runat="server"  />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" id="cancel_return" runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" runat="server" id="notify_url" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" runat="server" id="currency_code" />

<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="item_name_1" name="item_name_1" value="Item 1" />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="amount_1" name="amount_1" value="20" />


<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="item_name_2" name="item_name_2" value="Item 2" />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="amount_2 name="amount_2" value="20" />

<input type="hidden" name="tax" id="tax" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />

<%--<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="item_name" name="item_name" value="Item 1" />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="amount" name="amount" value="20.00" />--%>
<%--<input type="submit" value="Buy!" />--%>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <h4>
        We are redirecting you to paypal
        <br />
        It will take some time meanwhile do not refresh ,go to back or close page</h4>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

and code behind is like

```
 cmd.Value = "_cart";    // set for multiple items or cart
            //cmd.Value = "_xclick"; // set for single item

            business.Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessAccountKey"];
            bool useSandbox = Convert.ToBoolean(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseSandbox"]);

            if (useSandbox)
                confirmOrder1.Action = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            else
                confirmOrder1.Action = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

            cancel_return.Value = clsAppConfig.CancelURL; //System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CancelURL"];

            @return.Value = clsAppConfig.ReturnURL; // +"&PaymentId=" + paypalParams.FindByText("PaymentId").Value;
            notify_url.Value = clsAppConfig.NotifyURL; // +"?PaymentId=" + paypalParams.FindByText("PaymentId").Value;
            currency_code.Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CurrencyCode"];
```

it works very well for 1 item but for multiple item i am getting error , please anyone can suggest me what i am missing here..?

Thanks
Arun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more then one product you will need to do multiple posts example also change the cmd value to "_cart"

```
My Cart Item 1:
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremailaddress@yourdomain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Cart Item 1">

    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" 
           value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/shoppingpage.html">

    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/success.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/cancel.html">

    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:x-click-but22.gif:NonHosted">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif" border="0"

        name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1"

        height="1">
</form>

My Cart Item 2:
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremailaddress@yourdomain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Cart Item 2">

    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="1.00">

    <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" 
        value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/shoppingpage.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/success.html">

    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/cancel.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:x-click-but22.gif:NonHosted">

    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif" border="0"
        name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">

    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1"
        height="1">
</form>
```

For more in depth detail on how to set up pay pal from scratch try this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/paypal_c_aspnet.aspx

Comment: I have already changed that in code however what is use of 
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"> ?

Comment: Its the quantity of the product you are adding to paypal cart i.e. if they bought 2 x product1 on your site you need to pass that on to pay pal

Comment: Yes i have also added quantity and checked still it's not working any parameter i am missing here..

Comment: I would suggest for now rather then posting to paypal first confirm all your hidden values are populates with correct data. Try displaying all the hidden fields on the page to see what they look like and from there you will be able to see what information you are missing.

Comment: Thanks but anyway i have also tried this also but paypal not give proper parameter which are missing.